# How can I render Parent component again after update from the child component

Tags: reactjs

Like the question I mentioned, how can I make the Parent component render after I make a change to the child component? I have asked this question yesterday but no one answered me, so I have to make a repost, maybe I am unable to explain it. I have tried some newbie ways on my own but it doesn't work. I am asking again.

I have a Parent component which is `QuizManagement`, I have a child component which is `QuizEdit`. I can successfully do the edit in the child component, everything is working great. Updates to the Parent component are not getting refreshed. I have to refresh the page manually to see the page update again. How can I immediately update it?

What I think is passing the data from the child component back to the Parent component that matches the data of the Parent Component, so it can change the state in the Parent component, that'll make the Parent component render again, but I don't know how or if this is correct or not.

Please help me out, here is the code, I'll shorten and cut some functions out since it not necessary.

The father component, which is QuizManagement

```
    import QuizEdit from "../QuizEdit";
    
    class QuizManagement extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                quizList: [],
                showHideEdit: false,
            };
    this.toggleEdit = this.toggleEdit.bind(this);
        }

//- Get the quiz-topic list//
    async componentDidMount() {
            await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/quiz-topics").then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    quizList: res.data,
                });
            });
        }

//- Just the function for hide and show the edit button //
    toggleEdit(i) {
            if (this.state.showHideEdit === i) {
                this.setState({ showHideEdit: null });
            } else {
                this.setState({ showHideEdit: i });
            }
        }
    render() {
    const { showHideEdit } = this.state;
    return (
                <div className="admin-table">
    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Quiz ID</th>
                                <th>Quiz Description</th>
                                <th>Quiz Time</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
//- Mapping every elements in the quizList//
                        {this.state.quizList.map((element, i) => {
                            return (
                                <tbody key={i}>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{element.quiz_ID}</td>
                                        <td>{element.quizname}</td>
                                        <td>{element.quiztime}</td>
                                        <td className="admin-button">
    <button
                                                className="admin-config-button"
                                                onClick={() => this.toggleEdit(i)}
                                            >
                                                Edit
                                            </button>
//- I implement component QuizEdit with toggle hide and show from above//
                                            {showHideEdit === i && (
                                                <QuizEdit
                                                    id={element.key}
                                                    quiz_ID={element.quiz_ID}
                                                    quizList={this.state.quizList}
                                                />
                                            )}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            );
                        })}
                    </table>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

The child component is `QuizEdit` - which is the button I implement, when every time I press the button it'll display a small table with a text field to input

```
class QuizEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.initialState;
        this.quizChange = this.quizChange.bind(this);
        this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    }
    initialState = {
        quiz_ID: this.props.quiz_ID,
        quizname: "",
        quiztime: "",
        quizList: this.props.quizList,
    };

//-Get the quiz based on quizID, so it will fill in the form immediately when I press edit//
    async componentDidMount() {
        await axios
            .get("http://localhost:3000/admin/get-quiz/" + this.props.quiz_ID)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    quizname: res.data.quizname,
                    quiztime: res.data.quiztime,
                });
            });
    }

    resetQuiz = () => {
        this.setState(() => this.initialState);
    };

//-The submit button is submitForm i created, I parse quiz into the exact quiz_ID I get from the Axios below to update its name and time based on the ID //
    submitForm = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const quiz = {
            quizname: this.state.quizname,
            quiztime: this.state.quiztime,
        };

        axios
            .put(
                "http://localhost:3000/admin/update-quiz/" + this.props.quiz_ID,
                quiz
            )
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.data != null) {
                    toast.success(`Quiz edit successfully`);
                    this.setState(this.initialState);
                } else {
                    toast.error(`Failed to edit quiz`);
                }
            });
    };

    quizChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };
//- It just the render from below with the text input and submit button//
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="admin-table">
                <form
                    className="create-form"
                    onSubmit={this.submitForm}
                    onReset={this.resetRole}
                >
                    <label htmlFor="quizname">Quiz name:</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="quizname"
                        name="quizname"
                        placeholder="Enter your quiz name"
                        value={this.state.quizname}
                        onChange={this.quizChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="quiztime">Quiz time:</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        id="quiztime"
                        name="quiztime"
                        placeholder="Enter your quiz name"
                        value={this.state.quiztime}
                        onChange={this.quizChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" className="create-button-form">
                        Edit quiz
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" className="create-button-form">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                    <br />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is how can I update the quizname and quiztime back to the father component or something like that so it can know that the component is changed, so it'll render the GET Axios from the father component which is

```
async componentDidMount() {
                await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/quiz-topics")
```

or something like that, so it can render a whole new list again with the newest updated without refreshing the page, I'm kinda get tricky in my head about this last step, because I don't know if this is the correct approaching method or not

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to re-fetch the list of quizzes after the PUT to `/admin/update-quiz` succeeds in `QuizEdit`. In this case, inside the `QuizManagement` parent component, put that `componentDidMount` axios call inside a separate function, and pass it down to the `QuizEdit` as a prop. Then in `QuizEdit`, in the callback for submit axios call, you can call that function

Comment: Maybe that's what I want because I don't really know how to do it so I'm not sure if what I think is correct or not, I'll try yours to see if it work or not, thanks for providing me some ways.

Comment: Oh, but if I but the `componentDidMount` inside the function, it'll not render the quizzes list at the first time for me, so there won't be any data to show in the table for me to edit...

Comment: Yes and then call that function inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I've been stuck on this for a whole day, you save me!

Comment: Oh but it keeps update infinite, maybe I do something wrong

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it, too! I'm happy now :)

Comment: @Bunny could you please post the solution as an answer so others may see how you solved it?

Comment: Sure, please wait for me a bit, I'm outside now, I'll write a solution in 1 or 2 more hours

Comment: @FabianLauer I have posted the solution, feel free to make it better or if you need the answer. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this based on the ways @Jayce444 providing me

at the Parent component, which is `QuizManagement`

I create a method that works as the same as componentDidMount, and I named it:

```
updateQuiz() {
// You can but method to get data or however you need in here //
        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/quiz-topics").then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                quizList: res.data,
            });
        });
    }
```

Then at the toggle hide and show Edit button, I pass it down as a props, which is the method named `updateQuiz`.

```
{showHideEdit === i && (
    <QuizEdit
            id={element.key}
            quiz_ID={element.quiz_ID}
            quizList={this.state.quizList}
          //Pass it down as a props here//
            updateQuiz={this.updateQuiz()}
    />
```

This will pass the props updateQuiz (which is a method above down to the children, which is `QuizEdit`, you can put your children's component here and pass the method as a props you need.

And at the children component of mine, which is `QuizEdit`

I have a `submitForm` that work as an onSubmit, whenever I click the submit button, it'll submit and the method submitForm will run:

```
submitForm = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const quiz = {
            quizname: this.state.quizname,
            quiztime: this.state.quiztime,
        };

        axios
            .put(
                "http://localhost:3000/admin/update-quiz/" + this.props.quiz_ID,
                quiz
            )
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.data != null) {
                    toast.success(`Quiz edit successfully`);
                    this.setState(this.initialState);
                 //You will add a method that we passed as props from the parent component here if the condition run successfully//
                    this.props.updateQuiz();

                } else {
                    toast.error(`Failed to edit quiz`);
                }
            });
    };
```

This will become a callback, whenever we press, for example, the Edit button, if it runs successfully, it'll update, then the callback run and the updateQuiz will be trigger at the parent component to run again, which will render the component right away when you interact with children component.